# Aruco markers pose estimation opencv for moving objects

Tags: python, c++, opencv, aruco, pose-estimation

I am trying to track an object in space. For the same, I have stuck an AruCo marker on the object. Due to the dimensions of the object, the marker is fairly small, with a size of 4.5cm x 4.5 cm. The camera is roughly about 50cm away from the marker on an average.

Here is the issue that I am facing. When the marker is stationary, the markers are detected properly. However, during motion, the marker is not detected at all. I understand that motion blur may cause this issue, however that is definitely not the only factor. How can I improve the detection of marker under motion conditions.
What values can I change in the `DetectorParams()` of the `detectMarkers()` of aruco.

I have gone through the documentation where each parameter is explained, however I have not understood which parameters to change.

Can I tune the parameters for this. Additionally, can I take advantage of the fact that I have to detect only 1 marker always? (I am already using a small dictionary)

My motions are more or less going to be arbitrary, so I am wondering if Aruco markers is the right choice for this. If not, can someone suggest an alternative to track a body?

Note: This is an updated version of a previous question, however, since there were major edits required, I have deleted the question and created a new one

Thanks!

Comment: can you show sample images (stationary and moving)? Can you increase camera resolution and decrease exposure time?

Comment: Do you use a rolling shutter camera or a global shutter camera? Rolling shutter cameras (e.g.: webcams) are pretty bad at detecting non-stationary markers due to their inherent physical properties.